# Default values in database

Tags: angularjs

I want the current date to be added in my database while submitting a form.

```html
{{dateEmission | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
```

```js
 $scope.savedemande = function() {
            var today=new Date();
            var date= today.toLocaleDateString() + today.toLocaleTimeString();
$scope.savedemande = function() { 
 $http.post("/createDemande", $scope.demande).success(function(data) {
  if (!data.errors) {
   $scope.demande=data;
   $scope.errors = null;
 }
```

Comment: Please explain your problem

Comment: Okay, so i have a form, after submiting i want that the current date will be saved in my entiy, but with that code, the filed for date is empty in my database.

Comment: here you are not passing the date in your http post request `$http.post("/createDemande", $scope.demande)`. you are passing **$scope.demande** right

Comment: Calculate current date / time on backend side and add it.

Comment: yes i'm passing an object @SyamPillai

Answer (score 0):

Change your `http` request into

```
$http.post("/createDemande", {date : date})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a field in collection like this

"created_on : { type: Date, default: Date.now }" in mongo, no need to pass in params.

Answer (score 0):

So i make it  with initializing the dateEmission in my backend.

```
 @Column(name = "date_emission")
    private Date dateEmission = new Date();
```